# How to extract vb forms from exe file or project file

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

I have to formate my PC. I have installed Visual Studio again. Earlier I have a project
on Visual Basic. I have the Project files saved as .VBP extn and also have and ExE file for
the same project. It is also running. But How can I retrieve the Forms i have created in VB from these Exe and Project file.

Answer (score 0):

Let's clear something out of the way first, there's **no** strightforward way to get those forms out of the .exe file, so **that** is not an option.

On the other hand, the .vbp file is the project file, it **does not** contain the forms themselves, but it can help you locate them forms.

Visual basic doesn't require for the form files (.frm) to be stored on the same folder as the project file, that is why the project file stores the location of those forms. All you have to do is **right click** on your VBP file and select open with from the context menu, then select notepad from the list and you will see the plain text contents of your VBP file. Around the top there should be a few lines that look like these (depending on how many forms your project has):

Form=Form1.frm
Form=....\Form2.frm
Form=..........\Source Code\Form3.frm

Those are the "relative" paths of each of the frm files on the project. If yours looks like the first one where there's no path, then it means the frm files where stored in the same folder of the vbp and you have lost them (someone might have deleted them, or not copied them when they sent you the project), in that case there's nothing you can do to retrieve them.
But if the lines on your vbp file look like the second and third line, then search into those folders and the form files "should" be there, but unfortunately there's no warranty.

Hope that helps!